# Limit the results of a select from geo.places.neighbors in yql to a max. distance

Tags: yql, geo

with

```
select placeTypeName, name from geo.places.neighbors where neighbor_woeid in (select woeid from geo.places where text="sunnyvale, usa" limit 1)
```

i can get neighbor places from a location via YQL. But how can i limit the results to a distance? 10km, 20km, 30km ..

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think the geo API's provides this functionality. Check [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/forum/GeoPlanet-General-Discussion/Re-how-to-get-near-places/1306818838000-2a49ccad-c3ec-3170-8886-74af815b5780). There might be a way though. You could calculate this in your table definition yourself. You can get the result from the above query and then filter the results based on distance. Check the distVincenty function [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/how-to-create-a-web-service-in-a-matter-of-minutes/).

Comment: Thx. Meanwhile i have build an own webservice based on the opengeodb that works fine.

But i'll have a closer look at your second link for making things easier.